# Get last item active name on the list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can i have the last item on the list where the case it is success?

```
children: [
   {
    case: "no-success",
    name: "bruno",
    endOffset: 5
   },
   {
    case: "no-success",
    name: "pippo",
    endOffset: 5
   }
   {
    case: "success",
    name: "jo",
    endOffset: 5
   },
   {
    case: "success",
    name: "Matteo",
    endOffset: 5
   },
   {
    case: "np-success",
    name: "Robert",
    endOffset: 5
   }
]
```

I need to have the item where the name is Matteo.

Example for have the first i do : var foundIdx = this.newListWords[i].children.find(item => item.case === 'success').

Answer (score 3):

Definition:

> The find() method returns the FIRST element in the provided array that
> satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the
> testing function, undefined is returned.

You can reverse array:

```
this.newListWords[i].children.reverse().find(item => item.case === 'success')
```

Or you can use filter and get last child

```
const filtered = this.newListWords[i].children.filter(item => item.case === 'success')
const lastFind = filtered[filtered.length-1]
```

Comment: Thanks Jacopo good solution, i'm use the filter so i have the first and the last and not need to use the find

Answer (score 0):

```js
function lastSuccess(list: any[]): any {
  const SUCCESS_STRING = 'success';
  const [lastItem] = list // Take the list's head
    .filter(o => o.success === SUCCESS_STRING) // Filter for success
    .reverse(); // Reverse the list
  return lastItem;
}
const item = lastSuccess(this.newListWords[i].children);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var children = [
       {
        case: "no-success",
        name: "bruno",
        endOffset: 5
       },
       {
        case: "no-success",
        name: "pippo",
        endOffset: 5
       },
       {
        case: "success",
        name: "jo",
        endOffset: 5
       },
       {
        case: "success",
        name: "Matteo",
        endOffset: 5
       },
       {
        case: "np-success",
        name: "Robert",
        endOffset: 5
       }
    ];
    
    function getLastSuccess(children) {
        if (!Array.isArray(children)) {
            return {};
        }
        for (var i = children.length - 1, o; o = children[i]; i--) {
            if (o.case === 'success') {
                return o;
            }
        }
    }
    
    console.log(getLastSuccess(children));
```

Answer (score 0):

Single line code

```
let v = children.reduce((s, c) => { if (c.case === "success") { return c }  else { return s } }, null);
```

You will get null if there is no success.

Answer (score 0):

This should find the last item in the filtered array with 'success',

```
children.findLast(item => item.case === 'success')
```